# PyTorch degree with negative power produces error?

Tags: python, pytorch

I am getting a confusing error that I'm not sure why is occurring. This is the error I am getting:

```
torch.Size([24047])
tensor([1315, 1318, 1472, 1454, 1318, 1337, 1453, 1454, 1317, 1310])

Traceback (most recent call last):
    ...
    deg_inv = deg.pow(-1)
RuntimeError: Integers to negative integer powers are not allowed.
```

And this is part of the code:

```
from torch_scatter import scatter_add
from torch_geometric.utils import add_remaining_self_loops, add_self_loops, remove_self_loops
...
    if edge_weight ==None:
        edge_weight = torch.ones((edge_index.size(1), ), dtype=dtype,
                                     device=edge_index.device)
    fill_value = 1
    edge_index, edge_weight = add_self_loops(
        edge_index, edge_weight, fill_value, num_nodes)  
    row, col = edge_index
    deg = scatter_add(edge_weight, row, dim=0, dim_size=num_nodes)

    print(deg.size())
    print(deg[:10])

    deg_inv = deg.pow(-1)
```

I have not found anything related to this online. I'm not sure why this would be occurring?

Answer (score 0):

Your `deg` tensor is stored as `int` type. Quite reasonably, if you do a binary operation between integer-type tensors, it is assumed that you should still get integer output. However, with `pow`, if the input is `2` and the power is `-1`, even though both operands are of integer type, the output `0.5` is not. And I guess pytorch simply forbids this.

To solve it, either turn the input `deg` to float first:

```
deg = deg.float()
deg_inv = deg.pow(-1)
```

or pass `-1.` in `pow`:

```
deg_inv = deg.pow(-1.)
```

Comment: Thank you. Do you know why is `scatter_add` returning an `int` Tensor? In the example within the docs (https://pytorch-scatter.readthedocs.io/en/1.3.0/functions/add.html), the return type is a `FloatTensor`, but there doesn't seem to be any obvious difference.

Comment: @VictorM Is your `edge_weight` also `int` type?

Comment: @VictorM Also, in the link you provided, its example code snippet initialized `src` with `torch.Tensor`, which is by default `float32` even if you write integers; unlike `torch.tensor`, which is `int64` if you write integers,